# Texture Bake Still Doesn't Match The Original Texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, normal-map

I can't get this ground texture to bake properly. I made a video of myself baking the ground texture in this video: https://youtu.be/5M787vD3R8o . I was able to improve this bake (thanks to some help from a previous post), by changing the UV mapping to "Project from View," upsacaling the pixels of the image to 6000px by 6000px, and unchecking direct and indirect lighting in the render settings.

Here are some pics of the changes that I made to the bake after I shot the video:  
[image]
[image]
[image]

These are the steps that I performed to get my new bake:

```
UV Unwrap the surface (UV mapping to "Project from View")
Create texture image node for diffuse
Bake with Cycles GPU set to diffuse
Create texture image node for normal
Bake with Cycles GPU set to normal
Create Pincipled BSDF node (I changed it to a Diffuse BSDF node)
Connect diffuse image color to Diffuse BSDF color
create Normal Map node and connect normal image color to normal map color.
connect normal map to Diffuse BSDF's normal
Create material output node and connect Diffuse BSDF to it
```

This is what the original material looks like without baking:
[image]

This is what the material looks like after the bake optimized with a previous post's advice:
[image]

This is an earlier version of the Blender File before I did the optimized bake via previous advice. https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Aa1-2q11oSf8mj9JxMPNTXy4yRC0t4o/view?usp=sharing

Even incorporating all the tips I received, I still can't get a bake that looks as detailed as the original. I want to move this terrain into Unity and therefore I won't have access to all of the complicated nodes that I have here in Blender. Does anyone know how to get a bake that actually matches the level of detail in the original texture? Let me know if you need more files or information from me.

Comment: Firstly, the color-space of your Normal Map Image texture should be set to "non-color" (you have it set to sRGB). Secondly, when baking your Normal Map, make sure to enable "32-bit float". Lastly, (and I'm not sure how much it's important here, I'll admit), most 3d programs favor powers of 2 for the final image resolution (ex, 2048, 4096, etc...). maybe try 4k first, then up it to 8K if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It still looks pixelated and dark though.